# Does food change with your Druid form?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid

Does food in the Druid form change size with you? Let's say you transform into an Allosaurus, and eat an entire deer, when you transform back would your stomach explode from having a deer in it, or would it shrink with my form? If I ate part of a crumb as a fly, would I be full when I transform back to my normal form?

Comment: Hi! What problem are you trying to fix with this question, so we might better be able to help you out?

Comment: Ok, different way of asking. Is there a reason that the existing druid rule that all of your gear transforms with you is an unsatisfactory answer to this question? Could you explain that, and help us understand how an answer to this question would/should affect gameplay? It'd be helpful in order to provide better answers than mere speculation.

Comment: I think his hope is he can transform into a tiny creature, eat a tiny amount of food/water then transform back and be "sustained"

Comment: @ohmusama Maybe. It would be good for the question to ask that clearly, if that's really the main point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ask your DM**

This is not covered by any rule in the PHB or DMG. The only rule that comes a little close to this would be equipment, but that doesn't sufficiently cover it. Personally, I would rule that the food in your stomach is part of you, and it would change size with you, but it is not covered by any current rules, and is therefore up to your DM.

Answer (score -2):

Since the transformation can be considered magical, I believe your stomach size changes in percentages. For example: when you eat an entire deer when transformed into an Allosaurus, you are 100% full. When you transform back into your human self, you're still 100% full.

Your stomach can then be compared to Hermiones handbag (Harry Potter) or Nakors rucksack (Riftwar Cycle).

But as wax eagle suggests, this is all pure speculation.